# Xamarin Forms Rounded Images For iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, rounded-corners

I can only see the rounded images in Android, I tried it on iOS and they appear as squares.

```
            <StackLayout>
                         <RelativeLayout>
                            <Frame CornerRadius="60" 
                                  HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=190,Tablet=355}"
                                  WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=380,Tablet=710}"
                                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                  Padding="0"
                                  IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=15,Tablet=30}"
                                  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=30,Tablet=30}">
                              <Image Source="kuwait3.jpg" 
                                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=70,Tablet=310}"
                                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=70,Tablet=500}"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: U need bind and get data from corner radius by dividing height / 2 and width / 2 so if give an example if your height is 80 and width is 80 then your corner radius should be 40 in order to keep it center also your vertical and horizontal option should be center

Comment: <Frame vertical="center" horizontal="center" height= 100 width = 100 CornerRaduis="50" padding="0"><Image  aspect ="fill"/><Frame>

Comment: IsClippedToBounds="True" can help if you still cant see image clipped to frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your frame round and then your image will be round too:

```
<StackLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Frame CornerRadius="95" 
                              HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=190,Tablet=355}"
                              WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=190,Tablet=710}"
                              HorizontalOptions="Center"
                              Padding="0"
                              IsClippedToBounds="True"
                              RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=15,Tablet=30}"
                              RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=30,Tablet=30}">
            <Image Source="Images1" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=70,Tablet=310}"
                                 RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{OnIdiom Phone=70,Tablet=500}"/>
        </Frame>
    </RelativeLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

The `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` should be same, and the `CornerRadius` should be half of `HeightRequest/WidthRequest`.